# confusing notation in C++ (OMNeT++)

Tags: c++, pointers, omnet++

While going through the OMNeT tutorials given at: http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/part2.html at tutorial 9 I came across some confusing notation:

```
void Tic9::sendCopyOf(cMessage *msg)
{
    cMessage *copy = (cMessage *) msg->dup();
    send(copy, "out");
}
```

The code is pretty short and neat, however due to the fact that I have little experience with C++ / OMNeT I could not understand what this line here does: `cMessage *copy = (cMessage *) msg->dup();` , more specifically the `(cMessage *)`. I know `msg->dup()` actually means `(*msg).dup()`.

Could anyone please elaborate, what actually happens in the memory?

**post Edit Addendum:**

code for `dup()`:

```
virtual cMessage *dup() const 
{
return new cMessage(*this);
}
```

description for `dup()`: *Creates and returns an exact copy of this object.* 
Does this mean that `(cMessage *) msg->dup()` internally passes the address of object returned by `msg->dup()` to `*copy?`

**The other confusing notation:**

```
cMessage *Tic9::generateNewMessage()
{
    // Generate a message with a different name every time.
    char msgname[20];
    sprintf(msgname, "tic-%d", ++seq);
    cMessage *msg = new cMessage(msgname);
    return msg;
}
```

What does the `*` in front of class name mean here: `*Tic9::generateNewMessage()`

Comment: It casts the return value of member function `dup()` to a pointer of `cMessage` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that `msg->dup()` returned `void *` -- that is, a pointer to `void`, which means a pointer whose type the compiler doesn't track.  But you may know, e.g. because of documentation on that function, or because certain preconditions have been met, that `msg->dup()` will return a pointer to `CMessage`. Before you can use the return value as such, you need to tell the compiler what the type actually is. You do that by *casting* the `void *` to `CMessage *`, which uses the syntax you see.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens in memory. It is just a C-style type cast.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

You might want to learn more about the basics of the language. C++ is a tricky one to use.